# Accepting international payments

Tags: payments, payment-gateway

I would like to accept payments for international currencies, and also accept payment from foreign credit cards.
For example, I want to sell a product who's price is in ILS, and also want to accept local Israeli credit cards.

For the first part, does the merchant handle this, or do I have to do a currency conversion myself?

For the second part, just simply is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

> For the first part, does the merchant
>   handle this, or do I have to do a
>   currency conversion myself?

Depends on the payment provider you choose. Some will do it for you, some won't.

> For the second part, just simply is
>   this possible to do?

Depends on the payment provider you choose. But it should be possible unless Israeli credit cards are not allowed to be used internationally.